# Why synchronized method cannot cause deadLock

Tags: java, deadlock, synchronized

I use synchronized to test deadLock, and I find synchronized cannot cause deadLock by adding it on method. Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DeadLock t1 = new DeadLock();
    DeadLock t2 = new DeadLock();
    new Thread(() -> {
        t1.m1();
    }).start();
    new Thread(() -> {
        t2.m1();
    }).start();


}

synchronized void m1() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":m1 start");
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":m1 waiting to get m2");
    m2();
}

synchronized void m2() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":m2 start");
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":m2 waiting to get m1");
    m1();
}
```

Why the synchronized method cannot cause deadLock, it always executes in a circle.

Comment: It can, but your code doesn't exercise it.

Comment: Your two thread are use two different locks. How could this lead to deadLock?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `m1()` method on two different instances. `synchronized` keyword blocks concurrent access to *same object* from multiple synchronized blocks/methods. [Read this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

To cause a dead-lock, two threads should demand a resource currently taken by the other thread.

This code will successfully trap in dead-lock!

```java
public class DeadLock {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeadLock t1 = new DeadLock();
        DeadLock t2 = new DeadLock();
        t1.setOther(t2);
        t2.setOther(t1);

        new Thread(() -> {
            t1.m1();
        }).start();
        new Thread(() -> {
            t2.m1();
        }).start();

    }

    private DeadLock other;
    public void setOther(DeadLock other) {
        this.other = other;
    }

    void print(String msg) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + msg);
    }

    synchronized void m1() {
        print(":m1 start");
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        print(":m1 waiting to get other.m1");
        other.m1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because implicit object monitor locks in Java are *reentrant*. That is, if a thread holds an implicit monitor lock on an object, it'll be able to execute any piece of code guarded by that lock. When a thread enters `m1()`, it's able to enter `m2()`(and vice-versa) as it already owns the lock. This will keep happening ad infinitum

To demonstrate a dead-lock, you'll have to use guard both the method with two different locks as:

```
void m1() {
    synchronized(obj1) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":m1 start");
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":m1 waiting to get m2");
        m2();
    }
}

void m2() {
    synchronized(obj2) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":m2 start");
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":m2 waiting to get m1");
        m1();
    }
}
```

And then call these methods on the *same* `DeadLock` object.